# Sending a request in curl via a proxy with a basic auth

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl, proxy

How do I send a request in curl via proxy which requires basic authentication? I've skimmed through the documentation of curl and found the options `-p` and  `--proxy-basic` but how exactly I could use them I couldn't figure out.

Note I don't want to apply the proxy setting system wide, I only want to send a particular request via proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the anwser myself after some more digging:

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html states

NOTE! According to the URL specification, HTTP URLs can not contain a user and password, so that style will not work when using curl via a proxy, even though curl allows it at other times. When using a proxy, you must use the -u style for user and password.
So I was doing it the wrong way :)

Answer:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119410/using-curl-to-access-basic-auth-protected-website-via-proxy-polipo